# In Ember, multiple URLs, same route/controller/view/logic, different filter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-cli

In Ember, I want the following urls to be handled by the same route:

- `/due`: Show all tasks with due dates.
- `/due-past`: Show all tasks with due dates in the past.
- `/due-today`: Show all tasks with due dates today.
- `/due-tomorrow`: Show all tasks with due dates tomorrow.
- `/due-this-week`: Show all tasks with due dates this week.
- `/due-next-week`: Show all tasks with due dates next week.
- `/due-this-month`: Show all tasks with due dates this month.

I was imagining I would catch all urls by the same route and use the "when" part ('past', 'today', 'tomorrow', etc.) to filter in the model on that route. But I'm lost and don't know where to look for answers.

For example:

`app/router.js`:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('due', { path: '/due-:when' });
});
```

But [this doesn't work](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/routing-dynamic-parameters-link-to/6050/3).

**Maybe I'm confused and don't understand Ember concepts. *What is the Ember way?***

### Update

Now that I understand that the dynamic part must be a segment, I am forced to do something more like this:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('due');
    this.route('due', {path: '/due/:when'});
});
```

But I realized that `{{#link-to 'due'}}Due{{/link-to}}` was just hitting the `/due/undefined` url, so `/due` is never getting hit. I guess I ditch the `due` route and just have `/due/all`? Oy. Every minute another compromise.

Comment: As a bonus, I'd actually like 'due-past' to be 'past-due'.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a due route with nested routes for the period. URLs would then look something like this:

```
  /due
  /due/:period
```

In the due period you would fetch all tasks and in the period-routes you would have access to the period params in the params-parameter in the route's [model-hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model).

See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments for more detailed information.

The Ember way I suppose or the way I would implement something like this is to use the new [query-params feature](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/) and declare the `:period`-dynamic segment a query params property on the due-Controller. With this you only end up with one route that is able to filter the due-tasks.

You can also specify if you want to query the server when a period changes or if you only want to filter the already fetched due-tasks considering that you would need to fetch all the tasks for the `/due`-route anyway.

If there was some kind of pagination in the `due`-route you would need to query the server for the different periods of course. See [Opting into full transitions](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/) for details.

I think query params is the way to go here because the period routes are not really nested resources and will likely display the same interface as the `due`-route. The only thing that differentiates the two 'kind' of routes (`due` and `due-period`) is the filtering. Thus I'd opt for the query-params approach here.

Comment: I have a feeling you are probably right. But since those views will be heavily used, I wanted to find a way without query params.

Comment: Why do you want to find a way without query-params? You still get the url-support and the linkability of the resulting url. It should also be pretty future-proof for your app because you will not need to specify new routes when you decide to add additional filtering (e.g. for filtering for specific users that have a task assigned or something similiar).

Answer (score 0):

If those are the routes you want, then there's no reason why you can't have them that way.  This router map should get you that layout:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('due'),
    this.resource('past-due'),
    this.resource('due-today'),
    this.resource('due-tomorrow'),
    this.resource('due-this-week'),
    this.resource('due-next-week'),
    this.resource('due-this-month')
});
```

Though, I'd probably go for something like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('due', function() {
      this.resource('today'),
      this.resource('tomorrow'),
      this.resource('this-week'),
      this.resource('next-week'),
      this.resource('this-month')
    });
    this.resource('past-due');
});
```

Then your routes would be:

```
#/due
#/due/today
#/due/tomorrow
#/due/this-week
#/due/next-week
#/due/this-month
#/past-due
```

*It doesn't really matter too much if you use `route` or `resource`, its suggested that you use `resource` for top level items and `routes` for verbs like `new` or `edit`.*

When it comes time to fetch your models, you'll just have to hardcode the values to retrieve, like this:

```
App.PastDueRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model:function() {
        this.store.find('todo',{due:'past-due'});
   }
});
```

And you can link to routes by doing:

```
{{#link-to 'past-due'}}Past Due{{/link-to}}
```

If you don't have it already, I highly suggest that you install [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) in Chrome and use it too look at your app, specially your routes. It'll really help you get a sense of what you're defining.

Comment: This is the road I was headed down initially, but didn't like the idea of defining individual route objects. Basically, I'm going to have a `TasksController` that will list tasks and have filters for due date and category. I want all these "due" routes to convert the `:when` to a standard due date filter, then pass it off to the `TasksController` and filter like normal.

Comment: You can still do that. You can define what template and controller to use in each route. You may have issues with linking to the routes though